# You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 2

Tags: android, android-studio, version, google-play-console

I published my android application in Play Market two days ago. Today I made update of this application. I changed the versionCode in build.gradle from 1 to 2, and versionName from "1.1" to "1.1.1". When I had uploaded the apk file in Google Play Console, the browser crashed. When I had uploaded the apk file again, I got this error:

```
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 2.
```

however there is only one version of my application in "APKs to diactivate" block and there are no APKs in "APKs to add" block.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution: I pressed "ADD APK FROM LIBRARY" button and there was my apk)

Comment: ..and if you would like to keep version code, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207456/2960949) post to remove APK from library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this things

- Try to push an apk with version code 3
- Make sure the apk you are generating is the apk you are uploading

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing a very especific issue.

Just change your `versionCode` to 3 and move on ;)