# Google Play 64-bit requirement in React Native Version 0.61 release

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, react-native

I used to use version `0.54` of React Native, but due to a problem with the 64-bit version of Google, I had to create a new project (I did not update this version, but I created a new version).

I am currently using version `0.61.4` of React Native

After I got the `aab` output and wanted to publish it on Google Play, unfortunately I still had the same problem as before and I get the following error

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 9.
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app

[image]

I put the `gradle` codes here for guidance

***android/app/build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.....android"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 34
        versionName "3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    //https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'


    //https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)


// FIREBASE SDKs => https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/android-firebase-credentials
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***android/gradle.properties***

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true


MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=key.jks
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=MY_KEY_ALIAS
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=******
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

***android/build.gradle***

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1')

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // FIREBASE SDKs => https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/android-firebase-credentials
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

[image]

### Update

I run the following in a terminal for get `AAB` file:

```sh
$ cd android
$ gradlew cleanBuildCache
$ gradlew clean
$ gradlew bundleRelease
```

After running the above commands, I will receive the following output:

[image]

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
>   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>   See http....
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5m 21s
>   336 actionable tasks: 336 executed

***After Upload in Google Console***

This is very strange

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you were able to upload the app to the Play Console? Did you delete the old APK/ bundle with that same versionCode from the play store when you previously tried to upload and failed? Your config and APK looks good.

Comment: @BenB Yes, I'm sure the app will be successfully uploaded to Google Console. I increase the versionCode every time because Google Play does not allow duplication with versionCode at all, even if it fails. Can you explain more about this (delete previous version). Many Thanks for your comments

Comment: It doesn't allow duplicate versionCodes, but you can delete apps from the artifact library. Found this guide that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822460/remove-apk-from-library-in-google-play-developer-console

Comment: @BenB I deleted all Draft artifacts. Should I delete Active artifacts as well?

Comment: I don't think you can delete them, they have been released to users. Anyway, that is why you couldn't upload the same versionCode of the app. Now you can. But this doesn't solve the problem, but try upload again anyway.

Comment: @BenB I did what you said, but unfortunately I still encountered a Google 64 error. I updated my questions, please read them if possible

Comment: You have to deactivate the previous versions that are still available for your release. Check ["Prepare & roll out releases > Step 2: Prepare your app's release > Android App Bundles and APKs to deactivate"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=en#apks_to_deactivate).

Comment: @ChristosLytras Many Thanks for your answer. This was great and my problem was solved. Please provide this as an answer so that I can confirm it.

Comment: @Bashirpour just did thank you. There should have been a proper and more targeted message by Google Play regarding this issue but unfortunately it's quite misleading.

Comment: @ChristosLytras I was confused for a week because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the App Bundle ABB file generated. The problem is that there is an older active release that does not include 64 bit binaries and you have to deactive it in order for Google Play to process the new release.

Please check ["Step 2: Prepare your app's release > Android App Bundles and APKs to deactivate"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=en#apks_to_deactivate) in the ["Prepare & roll out releases"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=en) documentation on how to deactivate a previous APK/Bundle release.