# How do i delete/hide the uploaded release version from Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, release

How do i delete the release from Google Play Console?
There is no way to delete it as i can see without requesting to delete the whole application.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822460/remove-apk-from-library-in-google-play-developer-console

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859350?hl=en

Comment: Just unpublish the application

Answer (score 0):

once your app is rolled out and still in review you can't delete it , you can sumbit a new update that ends the review for the previous version and the review is canceled and starts again on your new release, if this is your first release and you are not ready to publish your app on playstore you can wait till it's live and unpublish it ,then when your are ready you can re-publish it , it won't be deleted it just becomes unaccesable from the store