# Version numbers on Google Play gets consumed?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to do some internal testing together with a friend through the Google Play Console.
I have set up my app, and followed the steps listed on their webpage and have managed to upload a successful build.

Though I have noticed, as soon as I press upload, the version number is consumed.
Reguardles of weather I save or discard the release. I think even so if the apk has errors!
This is very annoying if I accidentally make a mistake since I have to wait for the editor to build me another apk for 32 and 64 bit again with a new version number!

Why does this happen?
And is there some way you can manually delete version numbers that are not in actual use?
Having to wait for another build can easily take up towards several hours. And that is a stupid interface for something that is so easy to mess up. Any suggestions or best practices here?

Comment: You can delete the apk or the bundle, it's store on the Artifact bundle explorer. [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207456/15298643)

Comment: It didn't actually used to happen, when we deleted apk , we could upload the apk again . I face this issue recently too . There must have been some change in console .

Comment: Thank you, @javdromero I was able to find it.
Btw, it seems to have been renamed to "App Bundle Explorer" by now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to one of the comments I was able to resolve my issue.
The control panel I was looking for was just simple quite well hidden away.
(Or named confusingly rather)

Link to descriptive  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822460/remove-apk-from-library-in-google-play-developer-console/47207456#47207456)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to upload to Google Play if you only want to test with one or two friends. Just build and give the apk to your friends to install.

Version number in Google Play is unique identifier to one apk uploaded. If you can reuse the version number for a different apk or aab, it will cause big confusion when real user complains, as you lose trace which binary user is complaining about.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's just a bit more convenient to get good at how to actually manage a bit larger testing groups ahead of time.