# APK version code is 3 but still i get error " You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1."

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have uploaded apk with **versionCode 3,versionName "1.0.3"** but PlayStore gives me error with

> Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK
>   because you already have one with version code 1.

---

Here is my GradleFile:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "netsol.xxxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        incremental true
        dexInProcess = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you add the build.gradle file here and show where you have mentioned the versionCode?

Comment: you are uploading older apk to play store :P

Comment: increase versioncode just.

Comment: you checked the version code list on play store means what you have uploaded till date.?

Comment: My Last version code was 1&2

Comment: You need to change the version code in manifest also if in case you are using

Comment: i am not using any versionCode in manifest. @Anonymous

Comment: You might be running into the issue mentioned here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105406/you-need-to-use-a-different-version-code-for-your-apk-because-you-already-have-o

Comment: You need to change version name